# Laravel - how to access the relationship through laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel and Vue.js app that I am sending the comments through an API to posts page. Now I want to get the comments which are for that post through that API and here is what I have tried:

**commentController**

```
public function index(){
    $comment = Comment::with('post')->get();
    return new CommentResource($comment);
}
```

**commentmodel**

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

**postmodel**

```
  public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

and here is my Api route

```
Route::resource('comment','CommentController');
```

and finally here is what I get when I hit

```
http://localhost:8000/api/comment
```

which is all of the comments not the comments that belong to the specific post

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 33,
        "body": "a",
        "user_id": 1,
        "user_email": "a",
        "user_name": "a",
        "status": 0,
        "post_id": 9,
        "created_at": "2019-03-25 08:50:55",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-25 08:50:55",
        "post": null
    }, {
        "id": 32,
        "body": "a",
        "user_id": 1,
        "user_email": "a",
        "user_name": "a",
        "status": 0,
        "post_id": 9,
        "created_at": "2019-03-25 08:50:55",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-25 08:50:55",
        "post": null
    }, {
        "id": 31,
        "body": "a",
        "user_id": 1,
        "user_email": "a",
        "user_name": "a",
        "status": 0,
        "post_id": 9,
        "created_at": "2019-03-25 08:50:55",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-25 08:50:55",
        "post": null
    }, {
        "id": 30,
        "body": "a",
        "user_id": 1,
        "user_email": "a",
        "user_name": "a",
        "status": 0,
        "post_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-03-25 08:50:55",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-25 08:50:55",
        "post": null
    }]
}
```

Any idea how to send just the related comment to the specific post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

I changed your controller `index()` function to

```
use NorAm\UserManagement\Http\Requests\Request;

class myController{

   public function index(Request $request){
      $postId = $request->postId; // this should pass through you API. 
      $comment = Comment::with('post')->where('post_id',$postId)->get(); 
      return new CommentResource($comment);
   }

}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: postId

Comment: where and how should i define post id i mean should i define it ?

Comment: you want all the comment for specific post right? so you should have a postId.

Comment: yes and thats my question how to access the show method of posts and get the specific post id  in index of comments to pass to the where query

Comment: try `dd($request->all())` this will give you the request coming from your ajax. you should pass the postId in you API call. and you can access that parameter from your controller like `$request->paramKey`. Please see the edited answer

Comment: dd($request->all()) just returns [] and the   dd($request->postId); returns null a bit confused :|

Comment: and your edited answer gives this error strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190612/discussion-between-farshad-and-sandeep-sudhakaran).

Comment: thanks san as u guided me in chat i didnt pass the post id through my api and that solved the problem ]

Answer (score 1):

Your relationshipts seem to be correct, should be able to get all the Comments on a json structure with it's related post nested like:

```
public function index()
{
    return response()->json(Comment::with('post')->get());
}
```

Maybe you should check your database table structure and foreign keys

Comment: with your code again i get all of the comments and i have the post_id on my comment table which i think is fine not to call it in relation and laravel detect it i guess

Comment: If you have a correct pointing post_id foreign key on your `comments` table everything should work out of the box. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

In CommentResource.php you should return the relationship when available

```
return [
...
'post' => new PostResource($this->whenLoaded('post')),
...
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Am assuming you have post_id in your comments table. So for getting comments of the related to the particular post, you need to pass post_id(for which post you need comment) into your where.
So the query will be:-
`Comment::with('post)->where('post_id',$postId)->get();`
for fetching comments with related post.

Another way with your Post Model:-

And if you are fetching post and you need related comments with the post(your requirement).
then
in your model change your comments method with

`public function comments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Comment::class);
}`

`Post::with(comments)->get()`

with this you can get post as well as comments

Comment: sandana how to access the show method of posts and get the specific post id in index of comments to pass to the where query

Comment: @Farshad If you are fetching all post then you don't need post_id simply in your post model change methods comments `hasMany` to `belongToMany` and get all result with `Post::with(comments)->get();` and if you want to get particular post comments then you have to know which post comments you want, for this definitely, you have to know `post_id`

Comment: no look at this link http://localhost:8000/blog/8 its an specific post which i want to show all comments that are for this post

Comment: @Farshad the `8` is your post_id. fetch that id. if you don't know your parameter ( post_id) name, then you can get parameter name by `dd($request)`. lets say your request parameter name is `post_id` you can get this with ` $postID = $request->post_id;`

Comment: as i said you before you need post id for a particular post. so your  route is ` localhost:8000/api/comment` you not passing any post_id then how can you get post_id. you need to pass id first.  with this route ` localhost:8000/blog/8` you can fetch post_id because you are passing post id.